# Please help me out to convert the listbox items to list of array of strings in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have listbox and items are present in the list box and i want to convert those items to list of array of string like

```
var headrow = new List<string[]>
{
new string[] { "a" ,"b", "c" }
};
```

Please help me out and below is what is have tried and its not working

```
Listboxitems contains values with different items

     private void Exportexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginForm.qctd.IgnoreHtmlFormat = true;
            BugF = LoginForm.qctd.BugFactory;
            BugFFilter = BugF.Filter;
            BugL = (List)BugF.NewList("");

            ExcelPackage Defects_excel = new ExcelPackage();
            Defects_excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Defects");

            var headerRow = Selectedfields.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(item => item.Text).ToList();
            
            string headerRange = "A1:" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(headerRow[0].Length + 65) + "1";
            var worksheet = Defects_excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Defects"];

            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].LoadFromArrays(headerRow);
     
            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Font.Size = 12;
            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].AutoFitColumns();

            
            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.Title = "Save Excel sheet";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx|All files|*.*";
            saveFileDialog.FileName = "Defects_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".xlsx";

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileInfo excelFile_Defects = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName);
                Defects_excel.SaveAs(excelFile_Defects);
            }
```

Comment: Are you using VBA?

Comment: No.. I am using C sharp and i have updated the code of c#

Comment: Is `headerRow = Selectedfields.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(item => item.Text).ToList();` not producing what you want? It's not clear from what you posted where the error is. It may help to comment in your code the specific lines that are troublesome

Comment: Yes. the below 2 lines are causing the issue headerRow = Selectedfields.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(item => item.Text).ToList();  and  worksheet.Cells[headerRange].LoadFromArrays(headerRow);

Comment: It's helpful if you explain what the issue is as well as the line that gives the error. What is the result of the line you originally provided?

Answer (score 0):

Try `string(headerrow.ToArray())`

Edit: You may want to use

```
string myArray = new Array[headerRow.Count]
for(int i=0; i<headerRow.Count; i++)
{
   myArray[i] = headerRow[i].ToString();
}
```

or just convert to an array
`string myArray = headerRow.ToArray()`

It's not clear why you want an array when a list is generally a better use of memory resources

Comment: Explain me where i need to make a change can you elaborate please

Comment: Try the above Edit

Comment: in the above edit string is throwing an error invalid expression term 'string'

Comment: Edited, but the `(string)` method will fail if the object is not a valid string. You can also try the `.ToString()` method

Comment: Cannot convert to string[] to string

Comment: Using .ToString()? You may have to iterate over the list

Comment: I made a small change  List<string> headerRow = Selectedfields.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(item => item.Text).ToList(); and error went off , but however i am getting error now on the below line worksheet.Cells[headerRange].LoadFromArrays(headerRow);

Comment: Error message is coming in headerRow object saying Cannot Convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Object[]>

Comment: Can you try `.LoadFromArrays(headerRow.ToArray())`?

Comment: Cannot convert string[] to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Object[]>

Comment: Try the iteration method in the answer

Comment: I think i will use list more than array

Comment: This is more feasible and easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

ExcelPackage Defects_excel = new ExcelPackage();
Defects_excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Defects");

```
        string[] headerRow = new string[Selectedfields.Items.Count];
        int itemcount = Selectedfields.Items.Count;
        for(int i =0;i<itemcount;i++)
        {
            headerRow[i] = Selectedfields.Items[i].ToString();
        }

        string headerRange = "A1:" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(headerRow[0].Length + 65) + "1";
        var worksheet = Defects_excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Defects"];

        worksheet.Cells[headerRange].LoadFromCollection(headerRow);
        worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
        worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Font.Size = 12;
        worksheet.Cells[headerRange].AutoFitColumns();

        worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        worksheet.Cells[headerRange].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Title = "Save Excel sheet";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx|All files|*.*";
        saveFileDialog.FileName = "Defects_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".xlsx";

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileInfo excelFile_Defects = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName);
            Defects_excel.SaveAs(excelFile_Defects);
        }
```

}

Excel is just displaying the values one below the other under A1, instead of everything in header row